# Make nested child element full width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to maintain markup structure and have nested child element go full screen width to have different background color.

[HTML example can be seen here (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/e3sngy3s/5/)

```css
li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid pink
}

.section-bg-color {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
}

.page-bg-color {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-bg-color">
  <div class="section-bg-color">
    <ul class="addon-list">
      <li>
        <div class="header">1 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="1" style="display: none;">Hidden content</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">2 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="2" style="display: block;">Hidden content is shown</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">3 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="3" style="display: none;">Hidden content</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">4 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="4" style="display: none;">Hidden content</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have:

[image]

Wanted result:

[image]

Comment: Child's width can be done 100% based on its parent only. If you want to make child div "hidden-content" as 100% of the div "section-bg-color", then you want to make it possible with position:absolute. Until it is within the parent LI item, it can be made to take max width of its respective LI item only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make your hidden divs stretch full width is to position them absolutely, and will only work if none of the parents up to the page div are positioned.  Along with this I assume you are using js to hide / show these divs, so when you show the div, you will need to add some bottom margin to the containing li to make room for the hidden content.

Here is a quick mockup of what I mean:

```js
$('.header').hover(function() {
    var title = $(this),
        content = $(this).next();
        
    content.show();
    title.parent().css('margin-bottom', content.outerHeight());
},
function() {
    var title = $(this),
        content = $(this).next();
        
    content.hide();
    title.parent().css('margin-bottom', 0);

});
```

```css
li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid pink
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  clear:left;
}
.section-bg-color {
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
}

.page-bg-color {
  background-color: yellow;
  position:relative;
}

.hidden-content {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-bg-color">


<div class="section-bg-color">
<ul class="addon-list">
  <li>  
    <div class="header">1 Headline</div>
    <div class="hidden-content" id="1" style="display: none;">Hidden content 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>  
    <div class="header">2 Headline</div>
    <div class="hidden-content" id="2" style="display: none;">Hidden content is shown</div>
  </li>
  <li>  
    <div class="header">3 Headline</div>
    <div class="hidden-content" id="3" style="display: none;">Hidden content 3</div>
  </li>
  <li>  
    <div class="header">4 Headline</div>
    <div class="hidden-content" id="4" style="display: none;">Hidden content 4</div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3sngy3s/12/)

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but you can do something with negative `margin` and `viewport` units..

I've used a `pseudoelement` to make it stretch to the left edge.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/qfLoa3ee/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid pink
}

.section-bg-color {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
}

.page-bg-color {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.hidden-content {
  width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  margin-left: -100%;
  background: orange;
  padding: 2% 0%;
  position: relative;
}

.hidden-content:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: orange;
  width: 3em;
  margin-left: -3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-bg-color">
  <div class="section-bg-color">
    <ul class="addon-list">
      <li>
        <div class="header">1 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="1" style="display: none;">Hidden content</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">2 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="2" style="display: block;">Hidden content is shown</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">3 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="3" style="display: none;">Hidden content</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">4 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="4" style="display: none;">Hidden content</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT

To make this work for all hidden divs you can use the `nth-of-type` selector on the list item.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/1zmpcmv1/1/)

Comment: this won't work for any of the other hidden divs - just the second one

Comment: @Pete You're right, I missed that. Edited answer to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
.yourSelectorForDesiredContent {
    margin-left: -100%;
    background-color: yourColourCode;
}
```

That should pull it across the screen for you. Not the prettiest way but should achieve result you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid pink
}

.section-bg-color {
  //display:inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
}

.page-bg-color {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.addon-list {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid pink
}

.section-bg-color {
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
}

.page-bg-color {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-bg-color">


  <div class="section-bg-color">
    <ul class="addon-list">
      <li>
        <div class="header">1 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="1" style="display: none;">Hidden content</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">2 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="2" style="display: block;">Hidden content is shown</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">3 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="3" style="display: none;">Hidden content</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">4 Headline</div>
        <div class="hidden-content" id="4" style="display: none;">Hidden content</div>
      </li>
      <div class="clr"></div>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddler link is https://jsfiddle.net/e3sngy3s/8/